# Swift SceneKit — physical blocks do not stick to each other

Tags: swift, physics, scenekit

Blocks just crumble apart.
How can this problem be solved?
Initializing blocks:

```
var boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.75, height: 0.15, length: 0.25, chamferRadius: 0))
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: x1, y: y, z: z1)
boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = SCNMaterial()
boxNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "wood.jpg")
boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
boxNode.eulerAngles.y = Float(Double.pi / 2) * rotation

boxNode.physicsBody?.friction = 1
boxNode.physicsBody?.mass =  0.5
boxNode.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1.0
boxNode.physicsBody?.damping = 1
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfVvY.jpg)

[video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tl8dh83mrcpwja/stack.mov?dl=0)

[full code](https://github.com/phelder/JengaTest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to tell you how to fix it as I have the exact same problem which I wasn't able to solve. However, as I played around I figured out a couple of things (which you may find useful):

1. The same problem hasn't happened to me in pure SceneKit, hence I think it's a bug in `ARKit`
2. Node with physics has to be added to the `rootNode` of the scene, otherwise odd stuff happens (elements passing through each other, gravity behaving in an inconsistent way)
3. If you pass `nil` as `shape` parameter, `SceneKit` will figure bounding box based on the geometry of the node. This hasn't worked properly for me so what I've done (using `SceneKit` editor) was to duplicate the geometry and then set it as a custom shape for the bounding box (have a look at the attached image)

[image: SceneKit Editor]

Overall I've found physics simulation in `SceneKit` when used with `ARKit` to be extremely buggy and I spent a lot of time "tricking" it into working more-or-less how I wanted it to work.